Blender suddenly shuts down in a second when i hit f12 to render(in GPU Compute) a simple donut model with simple flower models on the background
for more info I use

Device name HP Victus 15.6 Gaming Laptop PC
Processor   AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics 3.20 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.3 GB usable)
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti
Graphics Card Ram Size 4GB


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you a Subsurface Division modifier with a higher level for rendering than for the viewport?
